# Error initializing DXA 1.7

Tags: dxa, web8.5, context-engine, microservices

Running my DXA 1.7 I', seeing a YSOD:

> Unauthorized Request -- Please check your configuration settings to
>   make sure your authentication details are correct.

Checking site.log I can see the following:

```
2017-03-21 11:47:09,158 [1] INFO  - -------- Initializing DXA Framework v1.7.0.309 --------
2017-03-21 11:47:09,206 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Common.Logging.Log4NetLogger' for interface ILogger.
2017-03-21 11:47:09,284 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Caching.DefaultCacheProvider' for interface ICacheProvider.
2017-03-21 11:47:09,341 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider' for interface IContentProvider.
2017-03-21 11:47:09,343 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Navigation.StaticNavigationProvider' for interface INavigationProvider.
2017-03-21 11:47:12,416 [1] ERROR - An error occurred while processing this request.
Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException: {"error":"invalid_grant"}
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryProvider.ReturnSingleton[TElement](Expression expression)
   at Sdl.Web.Context.OData.Client.Caller.ODataContextEngineServiceClient..ctor()
   at Sdl.Web.Context.OData.Client.ODataContextEngine..ctor()
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Context.ContextServiceClaimsProvider..cctor() in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Context\ContextServiceClaimsProvider.cs:line 35
2017-03-21 11:47:12,428 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Context.ContextServiceClaimsProvider' for interface IContextClaimsProvider.
2017-03-21 11:47:12,430 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Linking.DefaultLinkResolver' for interface ILinkResolver.
2017-03-21 11:47:12,432 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultRichTextProcessor' for interface IRichTextProcessor.
2017-03-21 11:47:12,433 [1] INFO  - No implementation type configured for optional interface IConditionalEntityEvaluator.
2017-03-21 11:47:12,436 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.BaseMediaHelper' for interface IMediaHelper.
2017-03-21 11:47:12,442 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver' for interface ILocalizationResolver.
2017-03-21 11:47:12,444 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.BaseStaticFileManager' for interface IStaticFileManager.
2017-03-21 11:47:12,445 [1] INFO  - No implementation type configured for optional interface IUnknownLocalizationHandler.
```

This looks like there's an issue connecting to the SDL Web Context Service?

Checking my Discovery service, I can see the Context Service is registered as a capability:

[image]

And even though I'm [having an issue installing the Context Service as a Windows Service](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16765/sdl-web-context-service-not-starting), I can run it from start.ps1 and if I try and browser I get the same invalid grant error from http://localhost:8087/context.svc.

I'm not quite sure what to check for next - from the logs it looks like the query to the Context Service has been made unauthenticated - so without getting a token first?

Is that right?
Am I missing some configuration?

---

**UPDATE**

So my Context Service now starts and using DEBUG I can see the following in it's logs:

```
2017-03-22 08:57:26,460 DEBUG VariableResolverUtil - Found parameter: ${oauthenabled:-true}. Resolved value: true
```

So I assume OAuth is on for the Context Service.
I found the same line when logging the Discovery Service and Content Services.

Everything *looks* ok.
One confusing thing I did notice is and error logged against the ContentServiceProvider in the cd_client.log:

```
2017-03-22 9:28:40 DEBUG [Sdl.Web.Delivery.ADF.HttpModule..cctor] - Ambient Data context initialization.
2017-03-22 9:28:41 DEBUG [Sdl.Web.Delivery.DiscoveryService.DiscoveryServiceProvider..ctor] - Attempting to construct discovery-service provider.
2017-03-22 9:28:43 DEBUG [Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.OAuthTokenProvider..ctor] - Using token-service: http://10.10.1.132:8082/token.svc
2017-03-22 9:28:43 DEBUG [Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.OAuthTokenProvider.CreateOrRefreshToken] - Attempting to get token from token-service.
2017-03-22 9:28:43 DEBUG [Sdl.Web.Delivery.DiscoveryService.DiscoveryServiceProvider..ctor] - Finished constructing discovery-service provider.
2017-03-22 9:28:43 ERROR [Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.ContentServiceProvider..ctor]
        Problem authenticating with service. Please make sure your authentication settings are correct and you have enabled authentication.
```

But the error is still coming from the ContextServiceClaimsProvider in site.log (shown above).

I guess this is the same root cause?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the DXA log file, the problem indeed seems to be in the Context Service: it returned an "invalid_grant" error. In general, CIS microservices do that if they are configured for OAuth authentication, but no OAuth bearer token is provided by the client (indeed, a browser will never do that).

The CIL Context Client (used by DXA) should automatically provide an OAuth bearer token if the Discovery Service is configured for OAuth authentication and a Token Service Capability is registered.

If you get this error on the Context Service only, it seems that your CD Environment is configured to not do OAuth, except for the Context Service.

BTW: I noticed in the screenshot that the Context Service Capability is registered with a `localhost` URL. Note that this means it will only work if the client (Web App) runs on the same host.

Comment: You can see form the screen shot that the Token Service Capability is registered. Also, my understanding is that OAuth is on "out-of-the-box" and I have no config that changes this default in any of the microservices.

Comment: I could see that, indeed, but not whether OAuth is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in my case turned out to be incorrect values in the `oauth-client-id` and `oauth-client-secret` app settings in DXA web.config.

Setting the log level to TRACE really helped here.

```
<add key="log-level" value="TRACE" />
```

Comment: Weird. If you configured wrong credentials, I would expect all the CIS queries to fail. Not only Context Service. Can you elaborate on what was wrong? Client ID?

Comment: Booth where wrong.